# Use jQuery animation only for non-phone size devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, jquery-animate

I have built and uploaded this site [here](http://www.peoplespropertyshop.co.uk) for a client. I used the Twitter bootstrap and customized it. My issue is the navigation it has jquery to animate the links. However i want this to disable and revert to an vertical list when screen size drops to phone size.

I know bootstrap already has the media queries built in but how do i do this.

Check the site and shrink browser to mobile size and you will see the list button appears but the links are still the same inside.

Not sure if i have made my point very clearly but more more info please ask.

Thanks

Here is the code responsible for animation:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  //When mouse rolls over
  $(".blue").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      height: '100px'
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 1200,
      easing: 'easeOutBounce'
    })
  });

  //When mouse is removed
  $(".blue").mouseout(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      height: '50px'
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 1200,
      easing: 'easeOutBounce'
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: In most cases question should contain a valid code, otherwise will be put on hold and nobody could answer it.

Comment: Sorry about that! Thanks for the tip

Comment: It also helps to make the title as specific as possible to assure more people will want to pick up the question. I've updated it for you this time.

Comment: thanks again Pavlo. I will ensure i follow these guidelines in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `matchMedia()` to apply an animation only on small viewports:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)").matches) {
  /* do animation here */
}
```

Of course you can change `480px` to whatever you want or even [check for other properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FMedia_queries).

Comment: if on small viewports i want the animation to be disabled and revert to ul. So could i modify this to min-width: 800px for instance